# Riemann-Roch Space for Quotient Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a curve defined over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Let $\{f_1,..f_m\}$ be a basis for the riemann-roch space of functions, L(D), for the divisor $D= t\infty$. Suppose you have a subgroup of the automorphism group, H. You can form the quotient curve $C/H$. Naively, I would like to say that the L(D) where now $\infty$ is the point over infinity for the quotient curve is just the function in L(D) above that are $H$ invariant. Is this right? Are there condition that make this right?